# Parametrization for the figure '8' curve?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

Is there a parametrization for the figure '8' curve, which is self-intersected?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a [Lissajous figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve). (If you've got an oscilloscope with separate $x$ and $y$ inputs and a couple of signal generators you can have hours of fun generating them by applying sine waves of appropriate frequency ratio to the two inputs.)

Answer (score 4):

An easier parameterization of an [8-like figure](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7B%20x%3Dsin(2t),%20y%3Dcos(t)%20%7D) is $(x,y) = (\sin 2t, \cos t),$
where $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi.$ It can easily be made more 8-like [by scaling](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7B%20x%3Dsin(2t),%20y%3D2cos(t)%20%7D).

Answer (score 1):

> $x = \frac{a\sqrt{2}\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t) + 1}; \qquad y =  \frac{a\sqrt{2}\cos(t)\sin(t)}{\sin^2(t) + 1}$

Check out this source:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli